# relationship between trace and eigenvalues

Tags: trace

Let A be a 10-by-10 matrix and rank(A)=1 then we want to show that the trace of A is an eigenvalue of A.
I know there is one nonzero row in echelon form of A and 10-1=9 free variable.
and also I know that the characteristic polynomial is 
(X^10)-tr Ax^9....+detA.
Thanks.

Comment: trace = sum of eigenvalues when the characteristic polynomial is split. Here it is the case since dim(Ker(f)) = 9  (Take a good basis adapated to Ker f)

Answer (score 1):

The rank of the matrix is $1$. That means the image is spanned by a single vector  in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ denoted by $v$. So there is only non-zero eigenvalue $ \lambda$ and the corresponding eigenvector  is $v$   and $ \lambda$ eigen space is spanned by just one vector (as it is of rank 1 ) which is $v$.So trace of matrix is $\lambda$. Thus by definition we have$ A(v)= \lambda v$ and hence it is an eigen vector.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- Using the rank-nullity theorem you have $$\dim\ker A=9$$
- The trace of $A$ is given by $${\rm tr}A=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\lambda_{i}$$

Comment: Can we say that trace of a n*n matrix always is an eigenvalue of that matrix?

Comment: @zeinab No. Take for example the $n\times n$ identity matrix for $n>1$. All its eigenvalues are $\lambda=1$, but ${\rm tr}I=n$.

Comment: Ok. but in this question how you show that the trace(A) is an eigenvalue of A?

Comment: @zeinab Try to use the hints I wrote. For example, what can you deduce about the eigenvalues from the first hint?

Comment: Is it ok if you explain that?

Comment: @zeinab I prefer not to. Though, I can give you another hint $$\ker A\equiv\{v\in\mathbb{R}^{10}:Av=0=0\cdot v\}$$

Comment: Do you mean that rank A=1 and dim A=10 and dim(ker A)=9 so A has only one eigenvalue so trace A=eigenvalue A?

Comment: You should write $\dim V$ instead of $\dim A$. Also, with a little correction your answer is right! $A$ doesn't have only one eigenvector. It has only one **non-zero** eigenvector.

Comment: Ok. I understand. thanks a lot, eranreches.